# REGEXP_LIKE() available in oracle but throws error when run on SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

Running the below code throws an error when run on SQL Developer:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('CTCP AYD 0404370713 M', 'CTCH.*[0-9]/{0,1}.*', 'i') FROM DUAL;
```

Error message:

```
ORA-00904: "REGEXP_LIKE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 40 Column: 8
```

Not sure why this is throwing up error when `REGEXP_LIKE()` function is available in oracle.

Any views from Oracle db gurus?

Answer (score 5):

`regexp_like` is a condition. Use it in the `where` clause or other places with boolean comparisons - e.g. `case` expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE('CTCP AYD 0404370713 M', 'CTCH.*[0-9]/{0,1}.*', 'i');

no rows selected

SELECT CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('CTCP AYD 0404370713 M', 'CTCH.*[0-9]/{0,1}.*', 'i') 
  THEN 'like this'
  ELSE 'not like this'
END rl
FROM DUAL;

RL           
-------------
not like this
```